# Why does iterating vector gives fixed addresses in c++?

Tags: c++

I have a vector of cars

```
std::vector<Car> cars;
```

My question is why do the following iteration yeilds different results

```
for ( Car c : cars){
    std::cout << c.getID() << "--" << &c << std::endl;
}
```

This resulted in fixed address as follow:
1--0x61fef0
2--0x61fef0
3--0x61fef0
4--0x61fef0

while the following iteratioin resulted in unique address per item:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    std::cout << cars[i].getID() << "--" << &cars[i] << std::endl;
 }
```

result:
1--0x8d18e8
2--0x8d18ec
3--0x8d18f0
4--0x8d18f4

my question is WHY?

Comment: Because in the first version you are taking an address of **a copy** of the objects in vector. Change it to `for ( Car c& : cars)` and you'll get the same results as with the second version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop variable declaration `Car c : cars` requires copying cars from the vector. To avoid this and just reference the cars in-place in the vector, use `const Car& c : cars` or `Car& c : cars` instead.